# Null Object Reference After Setting It

Tags: c#, object, parameters, reference, null

I try to explain my situation in a little code:

```
Class A
{
   private IDBTransaction trans;
   private IDBConnection conn;

   void Main()
   {
       B test = new B(trans)
       [some instruction]
       trans = conn.BeginTrans();
       test.Save();
   }
}

Class B
{
   private IDBTransaction trans;

   public B(IDBTransaction transaction)
   {
      trans = transaction;
   }

   void Save()
   {
      [some instruction that use transaction]
   }
}
```

When Save() are called the variable B.trans is setted to null because it was null at the moment when A pass the parameter. Then A.trans change its value calling BeginTrans() but B.trans still remain null. How can I solve?

Comment: Why not just init `trans` before instantiating your `B`?

Comment: I can't because there are many instruction before. I have to solve this situation leaving the B instance before the trans init. I only init trans where I need it, I can't init trans leaving it opened all the time. Is not a good practice.

Comment: Then make `Save` take the transaction object as a parameter.

Comment: Of course `B.trans` is still `null`, you didn't pass in a reference to a *variable*, you passed in a `null`-reference and the reference was copied. As such, it doesn't matter what you do to `A.trans`, it will have no impact on `B`. Therefore you need to provide the transaction object to `B` *when you have it*, and that means you somehow have to give it to `B` *after* `conn.BeginTrans()`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen is this the only solution? Passing it when it's valorized?

Comment: Or you will have to wrap it, so that you have "something that will hold the transaction" that you can have right now and pass to `B`, so that when that something gets a transaction, `B` can access it through the wrapper. Then you will have to give the transaction to the wrapper instead of `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hold you transaction inside separate object, like

```
class TransactionInfo
{
    public IDbTransaction Transaction;  
    public IDbConnection conn;
}
```

and then use it in that way

```
class A
{
    private static TransactionInfo info = new TransactionInfo();        

    static void Main()
    {
        B test = new B(info);
        //[some instruction]
        info.Transaction = info.conn.BeginTransaction();
        test.Save();
    }
}

class B
{
    private TransactionInfo _info;

    public B(TransactionInfo info)
    {
        _info = info;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        //[some instruction that use transaction]
        _info.Transaction;
    }
}
```

**OR** you can delay the moment, when you want to get transaction

```
public class ValueSource<T>
{
    private Func<T> _acessor;
    public ValueSource(Func<T> acessor)
    {
        _acessor = acessor;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get 
        { 
            try 
            {
                return _acessor();
            }
            catch
            {
                return default(T);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then pass any of solution above to constructor. Example for delaying (for holding in separate class example is same)

```
class A
{
    private static IDbTransaction trans;
    private static IDbConnection conn;

   static void Main()
   {
        B test = new B(new ValueSource<IDbTransaction>(()=>trans));
        //[some instruction]
        trans = conn.BeginTransaction();        
        test.Save();
    }
}

class B
{
    private ValueSource<IDbTransaction> trans;

    public B(ValueSource<IDbTransaction> transactionSource)
   {
        trans = transactionSource;
    }

   public void Save()
   {
      //[some instruction that use transaction]
      trans.Value;
   }
}
```

**BUT.** All examples above applicable only if you want to keep transaction reference in B class for some reason. If it is not necessary, I suggest (as was suggested in question's comments) to pass transaction as `Save` method parameter.

```
class A
{
    private static  IDbTransaction Transaction;
    private static  IDbConnection conn;

    static void Main()
    {
        B test = new B();
        //[some instruction]
        Transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
        test.Save(Transaction);
    }
}

class B
{
    public B()
    {       
    }

    public void Save(IDbTransaction transaction)
    {
        //[some instruction that use transaction]
        transaction
    }
}
```

Just to remember: dont store anything inside data structure, if it is not really necessary. Classes without state contains less errors and it is easier to test.

Comment: why you make the two class A field "static" ?

Comment: And I don't understand why u tell this is delayed.

Comment: ```static``` - just to compile code. Delayed only for - ```ValueSource<t>``` because if asking for instance only when this instance will needed.

Comment: Everytime I call ' .Value ' property he calls the Function that return the instance. I'm right?

Comment: what if I want to store transaction information into a class, the other way you tell?

Comment: Sorry, I'm in the programming world since 6 months. I'm glad to know what do you mean with "dont store anything inside data structure" and "Classes without state" with some Wrong & Right examples for your vision.

Comment: Ah, probably it was not clear because my bad english. I meant something like this http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/146508/passing-member-variable-as-a-method-parameter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126129/discussion-between-crk-and-tym32167).

Comment: @CRK sorry, chat is restricted for me, cannot participate at least during workday

Answer (score 1):

I would pass the `trans` as parameter to the `Save()` method instead of the constructor, it's kinda useless to hold a transaction reference on a object which has a longer lifecycle. *(at least longer than the transaction)* This way you can use the `Save(trans)` method on different/multiple transactions.

```
void Main()
{
    B test = new B();
    [some instruction]
    trans = conn.BeginTrans();
    test.Save(trans);
}
```

---

```
 Class B
 {
    void Save(IDBTransaction transaction)
    {

    }
}
```

---